# If props throw air outwards, why do some prop diagrams show a reduction in airstream diameter behind the prop disc?

Tags: aerodynamics

If props throw air outwards, why do some prop diagrams show a reduction in airstream diameter behind the prop disc, or are these velocity vectors?

1. Diagram showing airflow outwards as shown on nap.edu

[image]

2. Diagram showing reduction of airstream behind prop as shown in Zenith, Flying on your own wings.

[image]

Comment: This is Bernoulli's principle by definition. Flow after the blade runs faster, hence lower pressure and is pushed inwards by atmosphere. Or, think the total mass and volumn are constant before and after the blades, then the flow after the blade that runs faster must be narrower. Also, since some of the flow is thrown outwards at the blade, the flow after the blade would be even narrower.

Comment: @user3258438 that's an answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you have misrepresented the diagram on "nap.edu". Those arrows are outside the prop hub but within the propeller circumference, and the text clearly explains it's the swirl velocity, i.e., the circular (not outward) motion.

Comment: The outward movement only concerns the boundary layer, a much smaller mass of air than what is moved by the prop.